# lost connection to mysql server during query, help optimizing view query

Tags: php, mysql

I recently experiment problems loading the results from my view.
It seems that took more than 40 seconds and the connection to mysql get lost.
I configure this:

```
mysql.connect_timeout = -1
max_execution_time  700
max_input_time  700
```

hopping to solve my problem, but no changes.
My example query is:

```
SELECT usuario as 'Encargado', Fecha as 'Fecha', Periodo as 'Periodo', Area as 'Área', Profesor as 'Profesor', TemaAvanzado as 'Tema avanzado', Tarea,FechaPresentacion as 'Fecha de presentación' FROM tm_leccionario_view WHERE curso = 'S1A' ORDER BY fecha DESC, periodo ASC
```

I should have 171 records. But I steel have the error "#2003: Lost connection to MySQL server during query".

Then I run:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT usuario AS  'Encargado', Fecha AS  'Fecha', Periodo AS  'Periodo', Area AS  'Área', Profesor AS  'Profesor', TemaAvanzado AS  'Tema avanzado', Tarea, FechaPresentacion AS  'Fecha de presentación'
FROM tm_leccionario_view
WHERE curso =  'S1A'
ORDER BY fecha DESC , periodo ASC
```

and get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBbN2.png)

My view definition is:

```
VIEW tm_leccionario_view AS select s.group_id AS group_id,
(select p.nombre from parametros p where ((p.valor = s.form_id) and (p.tipo = 'CURSO'))) AS Curso,
(select ss.element_value from wp_formmaker_submits ss where ((ss.form_id = s.form_id) and (ss.group_id = s.group_id) and (ss.element_label = 1))) AS Fecha,
(select substring_index(ss.element_value,' - ',1) from wp_formmaker_submits ss where ((ss.form_id = s.form_id) and (ss.group_id = s.group_id) and (ss.element_label = 2))) AS Area,
(select substring_index(ss.element_value,' - ',-(1)) from wp_formmaker_submits ss where ((ss.form_id = s.form_id) and (ss.group_id = s.group_id) and (ss.element_label = 2))) AS Profesor,
(select ss.element_value from wp_formmaker_submits ss where ((ss.form_id = s.form_id) and (ss.group_id = s.group_id) and (ss.element_label = 3))) AS Periodo,
(select ss.element_value from wp_formmaker_submits ss where ((ss.form_id = s.form_id) and (ss.group_id = s.group_id) and (ss.element_label = 4))) AS TemaAvanzado,
(select ss.element_value from wp_formmaker_submits ss where ((ss.form_id = s.form_id) and (ss.group_id = s.group_id) and (ss.element_label = 5))) AS Tarea,
(select ss.element_value from wp_formmaker_submits ss where ((ss.form_id = s.form_id) and (ss.group_id = s.group_id) and (ss.element_label = 6))) AS FechaPresentacion,
(select u.user_login from wp_users u where (u.ID = s.user_id_wd)) AS Usuario from wp_formmaker_submits s where (s.element_label = 1)
```

Do you think the problem is on the defintion of my query? If is that, how can I optimize it?

Last week, when I had 1000 records on the primary table, I did't have this problem.

Comment: why do you have a , between `ORDER BY fecha DESC` & `periodo ASC`

Change the , to `AND`

Comment: Your problem is for sure that view, it's bad, but we can't really help you. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks @JurickPastechiGenaro but in MySQL I can't use AND in order by.

Comment: true, just came on the pc instead of being on my phone to look at the query even better and you are right. my bad i misunderstood!

Comment: I can retrive records using LIMIT 0, 30 (It tooks 40 seconds to resolve query) but when I change LIMIT 0, 31 I lost connection. Is there any configuration in the server (php, mysql) that limits this time?